# Javascript How can I get datetime string as "2017-05-23T00:03:21-05:00"

Tags: javascript, date, format

Now I want to get today datestring with javascript as format

*"2017-05-23T00:03:21-05:00"*

But it's some difficult.

I have tried as below.

```
datestr = (new Date()).toISOString();
```

And it's returning "2017-05-23T17:22:00.472Z"

Please help me to get good result!

Comment: Do you have access to npm libraries? I would recommend moment.js if so https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response, Stefan Theard. I will try it.

Comment: Just a note, you don't need npm to use moment, you can just download the source from github and add the appropriate files

Comment: Where do you expect the `-05:00` information to come from?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have fixed it as  moment().format().  Please add new answer, I will accept.

Comment: I will add answer myself.